# Data scraping using Python on a Jupyter NoteBook with BeautifulSoup Library

Tags: python, web-scraping

As part of Data gathering i've tried to get all the text from a web page and ran into some issues. the main purpose was to extract all the textual information that can be viewed when one opens the web page. in order to do so i've tried the following commands:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
req = requests.get("https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/0001652044/000165204419000004/goog10-kq42018.htm#sB8A92C82A7085B27A37F412D2216BC6F")
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "html.parser")
```

in addition to the above code the next command did not worked either:

```
print(soup.get_text())
```

that didn't give me all the needed information so I tried the next code -

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
html_text = requests.get('https://www.sec.gov/ix?doc=/Archives/edgar/data/0001652044/000165204420000008/goog10-k2019.htm#s807E96E4803A5E6491A43170CDE7BAF8').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')
paragraph = soup.select("div ~ div ~ div ~ div ")
print(paragraph)
```

in that code I was tring to open all the text parts but that didnt worked.

i'd love to know what can I do in order to get all the text data from the url using Python, and love to know what am I getting wrong.

Comment: What information are you trying to get? Just the section `ITEM 1A.` ?

Answer (score 0):

Data can be viewed using applying `headers` in request

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers={"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36",
        }
req = requests.get("https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/0001652044/000165204419000004/goog10-kq42018.htm#sB8A92C82A7085B27A37F412D2216BC6F",headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "html.parser")
```

Image:

How to find headers and `user-agent`: Go to chrome developer mode and refresh website and click on very first link to get details

[image]

Comment: isn't there a simple way to extract all the needed text?

Comment: i have added process for finding headers only you can print` soup.text` to confirm which contents all data but whats need to extracted from website i still dont know!